# Annoying menus popped up in dope sheet, can't remove them

Tags: animation

Yeah. I know it didn't come out of nowhere, I probably trigged it with the endless buttons or keystrokes everywhere. It's really annoying and it's the only one that has it there...

[image: The most ugly and annoying menu to be impossible to get rid of]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the dopesheet area, you have enabled [sliders](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/graph_editor/channels.html#sliders).

Disable them by unchecking *sliders* in the dopesheet menu **View > Sliders**.